# React - looping through values in render() function in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Rookie question, but i'm new to react and i want to loop the value from my state in the render method.

My current (working) code:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="status">{status}</div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(0)}
          {this.renderSquare(1)}
          {this.renderSquare(2)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(3)}
          {this.renderSquare(4)}
          {this.renderSquare(5)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(6)}
          {this.renderSquare(7)}
          {this.renderSquare(8)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

And i would love something like:

```
render() {    
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="status">{status}</div>
        for (var i = 0; i < this.state.squares; i++) {
          if (i!=0 && i % 3 == 0) { 
            <div className="board-row">
          }

          {this.renderSquare(i)}

          if (i!=0 && i % 3 == 0) { 
            </div>
          }
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Obivously this syntax does not work, but hopefully you get the gist.

Comment: try wrap the for loop with curly braces

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: @Black.Jack No. Statements cannot be wrapped in `{…}` because those expect expressions.

Comment: What version of ReactJS are you using v15 or v16?

Comment: {this.renderSquare(5)} Code smells - Consider working with another component named Square, which will have his own render function.

Answer (score 1):

The way to loop over in the render function is by using map.

```js
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="status">{status}</div>
                {
                    this.state.squares.map((square, idx) =>
                        idx % 3 === 0 ?
                            <div className="board-row" key={idx}>
                                {this.renderSquare(idx)}
                                // This makes sure no extra elements are created.
                                {this.state.squares[idx + 1] && this.renderSquare(idx + 1)}
                                {this.state.squares[idx + 2] && this.renderSquare(idx + 2)}
                            </div>
                            :
                            null
                    )}}
                );
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, ReactJS v16.0.0+, you could do something like:

```
renderSquareWithWrapper(index){
    const inclWrapper = (index != 0 && index%3 ==0);

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        { inclWrapper 
            ? <div key={index} className="board-row">{ this.renderSquare(index) }</div>
            : this.renderSquare(index)
         }
      </React.Fragment>,
    );
}

render() {    
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="status">{ status }</div>
        { Array.isArray(this.state.squares) 
            && this.state.squares.map( (_, idx) => this.renderSquareWithWrapper(idx) ) }
      </div>
    );
}
```

Don't forget to ensure you add "key" props to your `renderSquare` element otherwise you will get a React warning (it's how it identifies -- internally -- each component). The above example leverages [Content Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) which were introduced in ReactJS 16+

Comment: You cannot add a partial element with the && statement (<div> and </div>)
Your code would not compile.

Comment: That is just a binary check + React JSX can understand when and when not to render booleans

Comment: You can include an element, not half an element using this method.
Try it for yourself.

Comment: Updated solution to remove the half elements, thanks